# Send body in method GET axios

Tags: javascript

How i send body in method GET, but i'm not getting.

i try, but don't working

```
const res = await axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${this.state.url}Docto/Imagens`,
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${Token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    processData: false,
    data: { Id: 4075 },
    body: { Id: 4075 }
})
```

In Postman, the request normally worked
[image]

I know the correct would be to pass the parameter via querystring on get, but the back end did this way.

Comment: GET requests don't have a body. Any parameters that are part of the request are simply appended to the URL in a query string.

Comment: GET requests are *allowed* to have a body, but servers are supposed to *ignore* it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Answer (score -2):

`GET` request does not have a body, use a query string instead.
With axios I usually use npm [package `qs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) which is used also in [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/README.md#request-config):

Config:

```
    {
       ...
       // `paramsSerializer` is an optional function in charge of serializing `params`
      // (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs, http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)
      paramsSerializer: function (params) {
        return Qs.stringify(params, {arrayFormat: 'brackets'})
      },
      ....
    }
```